# Include file not in root directory yet include function works

Tags: php, apache, path, include

I know that this might be a silly question but I am completely lost.

I have been given an old, legacy project developed in PHP 5.3 hosted on an old Linux machine. The server is Apache. I have a relatively ok understanding of apache config, vhosts configuration, php.ini... but I am not a server guru.

The project is essentially a conglomerate of code and varying coding styles from 15 years of developers coming and going. I have just started sifting through files in the attempt to understand what was done.

I don't have the freedom to redo the whole thing. My task is to patch some stuff up.

In the project I discovered something that confuses me a bit.

There are a number of files being included without specifying the path to their location yet they are not at the root with the file making a request.

For example..

My project is in

```
/www/some_app/index.php
```

Some include file is in

```
/www/private/include_file.php
```

The index.php file makes a request

```
include('include_file.php');
```

Can someone suggest what to look for in figuring out how this works?

Is this a matter of settingup an alias that would treat /www/private/ as root (I can't see anything referencing it in vhosts) or something else.

I know I'm not offering too much information but it's all I have to go on for the moment. This could be something obvious that I am missing too.. I'm quite stuck..

Comment: Is the `include_path` being set with `set_include_path()` somewhere? Try using `get_include_path()` to see if that's the case. Or check your Apache conf file.

Comment: I'll definitely try that as soon as I'm back in office.

Comment: Also, try `stream_resolve_include_path('include_file.php')`.

Comment: Check also the `php.ini` for the setting of `include_path = ".:/php/includes"` does yours contain a reference to the folder you are including from